# C++ no match for operator <<

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is my code, I'm not sure why the error is being thrown - the method is supposed to operate on a pointer object and print out its values.

main:

```
cout<<"Deleted item is: "<<displayRecord(tmp)/*tmp->entry*/<<endl;


void displayRecord(PRecord* pr) {
cout<<"Time: "<<pr->time<<"\tEntry data: \""<<pr->entry<<'"'<<endl;
}
```

header.h:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct PRecord {
long time;
string entry;
struct PRecord *link;
};

void displayRecord(PRecord* pr);
```

I am getting this error: `error: no match for 'operator <<`

```
 error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](((std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Deleted item is: ")) << Priority_Queue::displayRecord(tmp)'
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:108: note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:117: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>& (*)(std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/ostream:127: note:                 std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is clear you want to use

```
cout << "Deleted item is: " << Priority_Queue::displayRecord(tmp);
```

but it doesn't compile because `displayRecord` returns no value. It returns `void` type what is not printable and cannot be used as argument for `operator<<`.
Call

```
cout << "Deleted item is: ";
Priority_Queue::displayRecord(tmp);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you added `Priority_Queue::` before the function call?

Comment: Hmm, i think it is namespace, what OP didn't show in posted code.

Comment: The priority_queue:: isn't necessary.